# How to animate/visualize rotations of shapes?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, animation, visualization, rotation

Can I use Mathematica to create visualized rotation of a shape? Specifically, I'm trying to draw a rectangle $R$ with vertices where $r>0$ and $\theta\in(0,\pi/4$):

$$ \\ R= \begin{pmatrix} re^{i\theta} \\ -re^{-i\theta} \\ -re^{i\theta} \\ re^{-i\theta} \end{pmatrix}$$

Then rotating it by $2\theta$ to create a 2nd rectangle $R'$ where:

$$R'= e^{i2\theta}*R = e^{i2\theta}\begin{pmatrix} re^{i\theta} \\ -re^{-i\theta} \\ -re^{i\theta} \\ re^{-i\theta} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} re^{i3\theta} \\ -re^{i\theta} \\ -re^{i3\theta} \\ re^{i\theta} \end{pmatrix}$$

Ideally the final graphic would start with $R$, then show a "shadow" of $R$ rotating to the position of $R'$. At the end, the graphic would show both $R$ and $R'$.

Comment: First you can use `Graphics` to draw your shapes parametrically and then use `Animate` or `Manipulate` to animate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RotationTransform](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RotationTransform.html)

> RotationTransform[θ, p] gives a 2D rotation about the 2D point p.

Rotating the rectangle around a selected corner with trailing effects:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}, 
   Table[GeometricTransformation[{EdgeForm[Opacity[.5 k/(t + 1/100), Gray]], 
     Opacity[.5 k/(t + 1/100)], Red, Rectangle[]}, RotationTransform[k, pt]], 
    {k, 0, t - 2 Pi/36, 2 Pi/36}], 
   GeometricTransformation[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}], Opacity[.7], Red,
      Rectangle[]}, RotationTransform[t, pt]], 
   AbsolutePointSize[5], Green, Point[pt]}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 3}, {-2, 3}}], 
 {{pt, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1/2, 1/2}}, SetterBar},
 {{t, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False},  FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Change the first control to `{{pt, {1, 1}}, Locator}` to rotate around an arbitrary point:

[image]

You can use arbitrary shape instead of `Rectangle`. For example, with

```
text = First[First[ImportString[ExportString[
      Style["A", Italic, FontSize -> 24, FontFamily -> "LucidaHandwriting"], 
   "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];
```

replace `Rectangle[]` with `text` and use  to `PlotRange -> {{-32, 48}, {-32, 48}}` to get

[image]